# Electron JS, Transparent window with frame?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

having some issues etc etc,

Working on an electron js project, and trying to make a transparent window with a frame on.

Have already been sucessful in creating a frameless transparent window, as well as a regular electron app w/ a window. Haven't been able to find anything similar through google (proabally my fault w/ non specific google searches).

As always, any tips, suggestions and help is kindly appreciated.
(through google searches in lmgtfy, it'll drive in the point to google better)

-- Switch

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a normal window, with all the operating system's usual stuff (close button, maximize, title etc..), and a transparent bit in the middle?

Comment: @FinnShadow exactly :)